# Why Having Too many arguments and methods in Rest controller here is bad?

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, controller, single-responsibility-principle

I have a controller which takes care of a user's first time journey at my website (ignore names of below dependencies, they are random)

```
@RestController
class Controller(
        private val fooComponent: FooComponent,
        private val dataComponent: DataComponent,
        private val userComponent: UserComponent,
        private val restComponent: RestComponent,
        private val calcComponent: CalcComponent,
        private val studentComponent: StudentComponent,
        private val tampComponent: TampComponent,
        private val checkComponent: CheckComponent,
        private val trialComponent: TrialComponent,
        private val reviewComponent: ReviewComponent,
        private val helpComponent: HelpComponent,
        private val achievementComponent: AchievementComponent,
        private val glassComponent: GlassComponent
)
```

As you can see, this controller layer has a lot of dependencies and also has 50 methods in it. 
It's usually accepted that a lot of dependencies mean the code is violating the Single-responsibility principle. But here, this controller takes care  of one user journey( like registration to my website).   what are the other downsides for this design? Also, Would appreciate suggestions for alternatives.

Comment: It's bad because your controller will handle too many responsibilities. Create a controller per component. PS : the suffix "component" is quite strange.

Comment: I would suggest you try a facade pattern. It just moves the problem to another layer. But the controller becomes easier to test and maintain.

Comment: Possible to share an example, where it is used?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your class is doing too much, but I can't really say without seeing its contents.  So I'll just talk about the constructor signature that I see here.

Passing in all of those variables is a form of dependency injection, which is generally a good design pattern.  But having to enter all of them individually, in the right order, makes constructing this class a nightmare.

This is a good use case for the builder pattern.  Rather than taking individual arguments, define another class `ControllerSettings` or `ControllerComponents` which has each of these components as properties.  Use that class to piece together all of the required compoenents, ie. build the configuration.

Then the constructor of your `Controller` class takes one argument which is a `ControllerSettings` instance (or ideally an interface fulfilled by that instance).